# Symfony No Access to Cache - Red Hat 7

Tags: php, cache, amazon-ec2, redhat

I'm running amazon EC2 VPC, normaly use Centos and I have no problem with it, but I have tried Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1, and I have installed everything from scratch.

I'm using Symfony 2.7.5, and I really struggling with the cache.

The web application seams to not have access to the cache folder (app/cache)

```
RuntimeException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2671: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/mysite/app/cache/dev)
```

I have researched a lot and tried all, change ownership, give full accesss to the folder cache...

```
chown -R root:apache app/cache
chown -R root:apache app/logs

chmod -R 777 app/cache
chmod -R 777 app/logs

sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:ec2-user:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:apache:rwx -m u:ec2-user:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

In the command line I can use **php app/console cache:clear** and it works. I dont know if its a problem with this Symfony's version or its some kind configuration problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your php instance running as `mod_php` or `php-fpm` ? This problem is related to user permissions. My guess is that `php` is running under a different user hence it can't write into the cache directory. Also, make sure you set `chmod -R 777 app/cache` after you run `cache:clear` as well, because the generated cache will be owned by the currently logged user (which is executing the command)

Comment: Hi, I think its running as `mod_php5`. I also believe the problem its the  `php` writing permissions, but I really don't understand why it doesn't work. If the owner of the cache folder is `apache` and if it was 777 permission, it should be able to work, right?

Comment: That's usually the case, but in RedHat you usually have `SELinux` enabled and set to `enforcing` (you can read more [here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)). You would need to fix your permissions and policies or disable `SELinux` to resolve this problem. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with `SELinux` so I can't help you further. Your question is more likely to be answerd on ServerFault. I'll flag it to be moved there.

Comment: @tftd `chmod 777` is _always_ bad advice. Nobody should _ever_ be doing this for any reason whatever, even "testing".

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it by **disabling SELinux** in this file ***`/etc/selinux/config`***
I know it's not the best solution because SELinux allows additional security, but this helps to overpass the problem until you find the best one.